# Rails testing default request host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I would like all my unit tests to use `www.test.host` instead of the default `test.host`.

I tried setting `ENV['HTTP_HOST']` in `config/environments/test.rb`, but that didn't get it.

My purpose is to avoid a redirect in my controller test, the output of inspecting the `response` object in my test is:

```
#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x000001059ed378, ..., @header={"Location"=>"http://www.test.host", ... , @status=301, @body=["<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www.test.host\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"], ... , "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80",... , "HTTP_HOST"=>"test.host", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"0.0.0.0" ...>>
```

If it makes a difference, I'm using Rails3 and RSPEC2

Answer (score 15):

You do it by setting `request.host` in your test.  You can do it globally by adding this to your `test_helper.rb` (in Rails 3.1 anyway, not sure about previous versions, but I think it's similar):

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    request.host = "www.test.host"
  end
end
```